# Android facebook integration error : following permission have not been approved

Tags: android, facebook, socialauth

I doing work in social integration project, in that, Facebook integration, in my created app i got following error in image,how to got that permission ? please help me :

Error : The following permission have not been approved for use and are not being shown to people using your app : user_birthday,locaion,user_photo

[image]

Following is the screen shot of in android developer page in my apps status & review

[image]

Don't have any answeres ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give those permissions while opening facebook session in your code...

Comment: i used github project in that it working fine but when create my own apps with my app-id and secret key at that time it create problems.means i just to change key.

Comment: hellow @Ricky you know how to get that permission ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than public_profile, email, and user_friends, you need to get your app approved. Click on the "Start a Submission" button in your app's "Status & Review" tab, and check the permissions you need, and provide a reason for why your app needs them.

Comment: i got all of the permission from the "Status & Review" tab, and put notes but not change it give same error as above screen shots.